# Changing margin values of images aren't taking effect

Tags: html, css, margin

**Problem :**

- I made my navigation bar images have margin values of 0px 8.14% 0px 8.14%
- Now I see that it is too much as when an image is taller than my
  screen, it makes a scroll bar on the right and for some reason the
  last navimg goes to the next line.
- When I try to change the margin values to 0px 8% 0px 8%, it saves and uploads alright but when
  I check the values in the inspect menu (is that what it's called?)
  it's still the old value.

The images in the slideshow are just random images to test capabilities and not what I'm using.
Also, instead of doing evil Stack stuff, **Can you please just tell me what I've done wrong?**

I guess I have to show my code.
**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href=index.html>    
    <img class="navimg" id="homeimg" src=Images/Home.png alt="Home"></a>
<a href=Webpages/about.html>
    <img class="navimg" id="aboutimg" src=Images/About.png alt="About"></a>
<a href=Webpages/contact.html>
    <img class="navimg" id="contactimg" src=Images/Contact.png alt="Contact"></a>
<a href=Webpages/extlinks.html>
    <img class="navimg" id="extimg" src=Images/External.png alt="External"></a>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 6%;
    max-height: 6%;
    background-color: #3C3C8D;
.navimg {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    margin: 0px 8% 0px 8%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

The full code is at http://jsfiddle.net/1s3byt56/ and my website is http://weeklyrandomthing.000webhostapp.com/
Thank you very muchly

**EDIT:**
I'm using FileZilla to upload to the FTP server (files.000webhost.com:21) and Notepad++ to edit the code. When I upload, all transfers go fine but the actual website doesn't seem to update, even with time. Should I ask another question to solve this?

**Edit 2:** 
Yeah I'm ready to delete this question now but I can't. The problem listed here isn't even the problem. My website just isn't updating. Peace out.

Comment: you mean what by `instead of doing evil Stack stuff,` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Marking as spam or dupicate or not enough info or any other things that this community is infamous for.

Comment: by saying that you will atract those things .. you think we have fun doing this? if your question is a duplicate I will mark it as a duplicate, if it's too broad I will do the same ... it's not evil, these are rules

Comment: by the way you may see that in your code you are using relative path for images so your code is not working at all, you need to consider adjusting it to make it working an also create a snippet here and don't link to an external website. [these are some of the rules you need to respect to avoid *evil stuffs* ]

Comment: The edit 1 sounds like caching or server configuration. You should ask another question. Make sure to tell who is the hoster/what's the server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox and define a height for the #nav. A percentage value in this place makes the result unpredictable.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
#nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: #3C3C8D;
}
#nav a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.navimg {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <a href=index.html>    
        <img class="navimg" id="homeimg" src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x300/?nature" alt="Home">
    </a>
    <a href=Webpages/about.html>
        <img class="navimg" id="aboutimg" src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x300/?urban" alt="About">
    </a>
    <a href=Webpages/contact.html>
        <img class="navimg" id="contactimg" src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x300/?animals" alt="Contact">
    </a>
    <a href=Webpages/extlinks.html>
        <img class="navimg" id="extimg" src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x3007?sea" alt="External">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sure it would work, but I think changes just aren't going through. Check my edit.